# How can I make this query in mysql with multiple select statements?

Tags: mysql

I want to make this query with multiple statements but I don't know how. Please help me. Thank you! :)

```
SELECT 
      customerNumber AS 'Customer Number', 
      customerName AS ' Customer Name',
      quantityordered AS 'Quantity Ordered', 
      amount AS 'Amount',
      SUM(quantityOrdered*amount) AS 'Total Amount'
   FROM 
      customers 
         INNER JOIN orders USING (customerNumber) 
            INNER JOIN orderdetails USING (orderNumber)
         INNER JOIN payments USING (customerNumber)
   WHERE 
      quantityOrdered >= 50
   GROUP BY 
      customerName 
   HAVING 
      COUNT(quantityOrdered) > 5 
   ORDER BY 
      3;
```

Comment: why you want this in multiple quries. This definitly a one query. you get results from multiple table a different data. if you want so mean all data from different tables throgh different select quries then follow my answer

Comment: Careful! You are misusing the MySQL extension to GROUP BY. You probably will retrieve incorrect `quantityordered` and `amount` values with this query. Read this, please: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/group-by-handling.html

Comment: Your query is not defining properly enough information.

Answer (score 0):

Too much to explain in a comment... Your query does not make sense and it may be due to a lack of understanding of the group by and having context.  I would first start that your queries should have all columns referenced as "table.column" or "alias.column" so we know where columns originate vs guessing.

The "Group by" applies an aggregation of values (such as your SUM() of qty * amount) by the given group by (customer name).  However, if you have multiple records in the child-level tables (ex: multiple payments for a person, then your counts and sum values could get duplicated unexpectedly.)  Also, you have a group by customer name... What if you have 5 different people named "Jim" but they are totally different people.  You should probably be grouping by their unique customerNumber, and this would result in 5 different "Jim" records with each of their respective unique customer numbers.

Your Where clause of QtyOrd > 50 means that only those individual line item purchases (assuming) order details, have a quantity of 50 or more will be included regardless of how many items ordered have less quantity even if on the same order which is ok if that is what you intend.

Finally, your having clause of count() > 5, this appears you only want those customers who have ordered AT LEAST 5 different things with a quantity of 50 or more as qualified by the where clause.

The order by 3 indicating you want ordered by the quantity ordered in natural ascending order (vs descending would be most qty at top, least qty at bottom).

All that being said, you have an additional join to your payments table.  Here is where the duplications would probably kick in...  If you have an order with 2 or 3 payments, your order of 2 line items has just turned into 4 or 6 as a final count.

Knowing these, you might want to better describe in your original question what you are TRYING to get.  You showed the query as best you could, but still unclear...

Answer (score -1):

as per your scenario and provided data is explaining i have get this type of things .. hope it will help you.

```
select * from orders where customerNumber == '';

select * from orderdetails where orderNumber == '';

select * from payments where customerNumber == '';

select SUM(o.quantityOrdered * p.amount) as 'quantityOrdered' from orders o, payments p where o.orderId == p.orderId;
```

Comment: Not even close to what the person was asking for.

Comment: as per my understanding i have posted.. thanks DRapp